# The form of an infinite product that converges to 1/2 or 1/3

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I have a hypothesis from some code that in the limit, the products of some variables become
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n a_i=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n b_i=\frac{1}{3}$$

I find that the terms $a_i$ and $b_i$ all tend to 1 as $n$ becomes large, and the products tend towards the values above.

I am interest to know if there are any general forms of functions $a_i(i)$ or $b_i(i)$ that satisfy the properties above i.e can we work backwards from the convergent solution to some examples of functions which satisfy these convergence properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is easier to discuss sums than products:
take your favorite converging series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty x_i =X$ where $X\neq 0$, divide by X, multiply by $\ln(0.5)$ and voila, $a_i=\exp(x_i\ln(0.5)/X)$ is a possible choice:
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_i = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \exp(x_i\ln(0.5)/X)=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\ln(0.5)/X\right)=
\exp\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\ln(0.5)/X\right)= \exp\left(X\ln(0.5)/X\right)=\tfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for this. I also have the condition that $a_{i+1}>a_i$, so I'll shop around for series that satisfy this... hopefully there's something simple (say a rational function) that works.

Comment: Take $x_i=-1/2^i$ ($X=-1$, starting from $i=1$). Then $\ln(0.5)/2^i$ is increasing and so does $a_i$.